# How to Unenroll Chromebook Acer C733?

Tags: chromebook

I have tried unenrolling my Acer Chromebook C733. Dev mode is blocked, recovery images don't work under v117 don't work and I have tried to disable Write Protection by unpluggin the battery, but it still didn't unenroll. How could I unenroll my Chromebook?

Comment: You can't. Please contact the owner for that.